# What is the shortcut to open the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal on macbook?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have been searching for the shortcut to open visual studio code Integrated Terminal on my macbook. In the menu it say `` ^` `` (shift 6 backtick) but this is not working on my mac. I am not sure how to make a new shortcut to open the integrated terminal.

Answer (score 6):

`^` denotes the control key. So it's `ctrl-backtick`.

Comment: For a non US Mac User it´s  CMD + j